# Computed properties in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I have a scenario where the data being manipulated on the client is presented and interacted with in a different way than it is represented on the server.

Consider the following `event` resource returned from the server.

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "start_at": 1331336004906,
  "end_at": 1331337704906
}
```

And the following template for editing:

```
<form>
  <!-- Notice how date and time are separated in the interface -->
  <input type="text" name="start_date" value="{{start_date}}" />
  <input type="text" name="start_time" value="{{start_time}}" />

  <!-- Instead of asking for an end date/time, we ask for the duration -->
  <input type="text" name="duration" value="{{duration}}" />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How would I go about treating `start_date`, `start_time`, and `duration` as attributes in my Backbone model without sending them to the server? Am I supposed to modify `.toJSON()`?

Comment: what is the problem with the event ressource format,arent they timestamps ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648990/how-to-access-a-calculated-field-of-a-backbone-model-from-handlebars-template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model should correspond as closely as possible to what you have server side. So stick with `start_at` and `end_at`. That will greatly simplify your `sync()` operations.

On your edit form's *View*, you can:

1. Compute `start_date`, `start_time`, `duration` through simple functions and call them in the template.
2. Convert to `start_at` and `end_at` on submitting.

Comment: Isn't putting this in the View going to lead to a lot of redundant code? I'll be using the same virtual attributes all over the site, where a single event has multiple views that show it.

Comment: No redundancy necessary. Make a base view and extend it.

Comment: Good call! I also think the decorator pattern could suit this problem.

Comment: Sure, if the complexity justifies going over pseudo-inheritance, decorator sounds like an excellent choice!

Answer (score 23):

I am using a combination of the initialize() function together with change event listeners to update derived attributes. The idea is first to compute the attributes on model initialization, and second to let the model listen to its own changes and update the attributes accordingly.

My solution looks roughly like this:

```
MyModel: Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.updateDerivedAttributes();
        this.on('change:start_at', this.updateDerivedAttributes, this);
    },
    updateDerivedAttributes: function() {
        this.set({
            start_date: Utils.dateFromDate( this.get( "start_at" ) ),
            start_time: Utils.timeFromDate( this.get( "start_at" ) ),
            duration: Utils.youGetTheIdea()
        }, {silent:true});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

We are very used to send `model.toJSON()` to *feed the template*. And this method is very tricky to overwrite because is used by other components.

But we can feed the template with a custom `model.toJSONDecorated()` method that can look like this:

```
# in your Backbone.Model
toJSONDecorated: function(){
  return 
    _.extend( 
      this.toJSON(), 
      {
        start_date : Utils.dateFromDate( this.get( "start_at" ) ),
        start_time : Utils.timeFromDate( this.get( "start_at" ) ),
        duration   : Utils.youGetTheIdea( :) )
      } 
    );
}
```

Of course this is breaking a few patterns, I can live with it, if you don't you can move this logic to a `Decorator` class as people have suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 5):

You have some options:

- Override `toJSON` to return the computed `duration`
- Create a `duration()` method on the Backbone `Model`. Only downside that you have to call it differently (`obj.duration()` instead of `obj.get('duration')`). In your view that hands `obj.toJSON()` to your template, mix in the `duration` attribute
- Use https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Mutators (or similar) to create a derived getter for duration

Comment: Thanks. I usually adopt the approach bes described, but I didn't know Mutators: it looks very useful and well done.