# Iterating over an array in packages

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I want to create a handlebars helper that works like `{{#each}}` but gives me the possibility to specify a number so that every `n` iterations some additional code is run.

The reason I need this is that I need to spit out the content in rows of three items, so every three items I need to open and close a new container div.

Of course I could simply let backbone format the array in packages of three items and iterate over that using `{{#each}}` but I thought it would be more elegant to create a helper so that I can say something like

```
{{#each_pack data 3}}
  <div class="container">
  {{#each pack_items}}
    <span>{{content}}</span>
  {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each_pack}}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to do this.
How do I make `pack_items` available to the inside block?

Comment: I don't think Mustache syntax is gonna be confortable with what you are trying. I think the pattern is to move this kind of _logic_ out of the template. You can use a `Decorator` for provide this kind of _meta attributes_ to your `Model`. Or add a [toJSONDecorated method to your Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642439/computed-properties-in-backbone/9687672#9687672)

Comment: I always saw the logicless approach more as a way to force you to write helpers for things that you would normally do in the template, such as iterating over the array and using the modulo operator to figure out if a new row starts, to promote re-usability and cleaner templates, not to move all logic to the part of the application that provides the data. Thus the idea to write a helper for this kind of situation which often arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in a way that lets me use the exact same syntax I just proposed.
Here is the code:

```
window.Handlebars.registerHelper('each_pack', function(context, packsize, fn){
    var ret = '';

    /*
        Function that creates packages of size 
        packsize from a given array
    */
    var packagify = function(array, packsize){
        var i = 0;
        var length = array.length;

        var returnArray = [];
        var pack = [];
        while(i < length){
            /*
                If this is not the first entry,
                if this is the packsize-d entry
                or this is the last entry,
                push the pack to the return array
                and create a new one
            */

            if(((i % packsize) == 0 && i != 0) || (i == (length - 1))){
                returnArray.push(pack);
                pack = [];
            }
            pack.push(array[i]);
            i++;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    var packArray = packagify(context,packsize);

    for(var i = 0; i < packArray.length; i++){
        var pack = packArray[i];

        this['pack_items'] = pack;
        ret = ret + fn(this);
    }

    delete this['pack_items'];
    return ret;
});
```

Comment: Yes, it looks nice, but still this is working because you are using [Underscore template](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) .. not real [Mustache template](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html). Don't saying is wrong just wanted to point out the detail.