# Backbone.js - How to use a custom model property in a template?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

This might be a really simple question but I'm having a heck of a time finding an answer.

Using backbone, I have this line:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend();
```

I then use that in a collection filled from a URL. For the sake of the example, say I have a first and last name, and I want to do something like:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    FullName: this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName")
});
```

I can call that inside backbone using, for example, People.first().FullName(). But if I pass People.first() to my view and render that in a template, it seems to have no knowledge what FullName is.

How would I add a custom property to a model in Backbone and use that inside a template?

Cheers!

Comment: you should do that in the initialize. ex:
`Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
initialize:function(){
this.set({"FullName":this.get("FirstName") + " " + this.get("LastName")});
//using set will trigger change event :)
}});`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `FullName` definition doesn't make any sense so I'm going to assume that you really meant this:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    FullName: function() {
        return this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName");
    }
});
```

Usually you'll call [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) on your models to serialize them for use by a template:

```
var html = template({ person: person.toJSON() })
```

The [default `toJSON`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.0.0/backbone.js#L281) simply returns a (shallow) copy of the model's internal attributes. The attributes will, presumably, have both `firstName` and `lastName` properties but `FullName` is a function on the model so it won't be in the attributes.

You could provide your own `toJSON`:

```
toJSON: function() {
    var j = _(this.attributes).clone();
    j.FullName = this.FullName();
    return j;
}
```

and then you'd have a `FullName` in your template. However, `toJSON` is also used to serialize the model to send data to the server; your server would end up seeing a `FullName` and it might get upset about that. You could add another serializer specifically for templates:

```
// `serialize` is another common name for this
for_template: function() {
    var j = this.toJSON();
    j.FullName = this.FullName();
    return j;
}
```

and then use that function to supply data for your templates:

```
var html = template({ person: person.for_template() });
```

Comment: Completely agree, my preferred approach is the `for_template` one, I don't like to tangle up with very core method such `toJSON`. Related answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642439/computed-properties-in-backbone/9687672#9687672

Comment: Nice idea to use `for_template`

Comment: @fguillen: Yes, this sort of thing has come up a few times. There is a `parse` method but no `unparse`, `toJSON` is doing double duty to serialize things for views and serializing things for persistence but these are different tasks. Patching Backbone one way or the other would be pretty simple, `unparse` would be more backwards compatible but `for_template` would make more sense to me due to [the specialness of `toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior).

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this for a while too, but I found a solution.

Its covered in a fair amount of depth, including a solution to the issue of toJSON being used to send the server data, in [Backbone Computed Properties](http://kilon.org/blog/2012/02/backbone-calculated-fields/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function (model) {
        model.FullName = model.FirstName + ' ' + model.LastName;
        return model;
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `model.toJSON()` will now contain a `FullName` and that means that the server will see an unexpected `FullName` when you `model.save()`. Sensible server code will complain about that API violation. You also have to worry about cases where `parse` isn't called while creating a model.

Comment: equally strip out fullname by overriding `model.save`

Answer (score 0):

There is a much more simple method.  Include your method inside of your initialize method.  When you instantiate your model all of your methods get instantiated as well.

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
 initialize : function(){
      this.myCustomMethod = function(){ return 'Something'; };
 },
 idAttribute : 'id',
 urlRoot : ''
 });
```

Comment: And how does that relate to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Quite different workaround:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    this.set('fullName', this.fullName.bind(this))
  },

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + this.get('lastName');
  }
});
```

THis way the 'fullName' function can be called directly on model

```
model.fullName()
```

or through `get` function, allowing it to be called from template:

```
model.get('fullName')()
```