# Client-side only attributes in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a fairly generic model and collection of that model (see below) I am dealing with as the basis for a series of views.  On several of the views, the selection of one of the models generates actions (via the 'selected' attribute), and I need to be able to keep track of the selection on just the client side.

However, it appears that there is no clean way to do this in Backbone. Any attributes added to/changed on the model on the client will be sync'd up to the server.  I can't use `{silent : yes}` when changing that attribute because I need to trigger changes in my views when the `change` event fires on that attribute.  The only way I have come up with to do this is to overwrite the `save` function on `Backbone.Model`

My question: is there a way to have client-side only attributes that I am missing OR is my approach structurally flawed in some other way that I am just not seeing?

```
    var CSEvent = Backbone.Model.extend({
        idAttribute: "_id",
        urlRoot : '/api/events',
        defaults: {
            title : "",
            type : "Native",
            repeatOrOneTime : "OneTime",
            selected : false
        }
    });    

    var CSEventCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: CSEvent,
        url: '/api/events',
        getSelectedEvent : function() {
            return this.find(function(csevent) { return csevent.get('selected') === true; });
        },
        selectEvent : function(eventId) {
            this.deselectEvent();
            this.get(eventId).set({selected : true});
        },
        deselectEvent : function() {
            this.getSelectedEvent().set({selected : false});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to override the `Model.toJSON()` method, as you can see in the [Backbone Model code](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L227-229) this method is not very complicate. Also the official documentation suggests to override it in case of special needs.

Try something like this:

```
var CSEvent = Backbone.Model.extend({
  toJSON: function(){
    return _.clone( _.pick( this.attributes, "title", "type", "repeatOrOneTime" ) );
  }
});
```

Comment: And he'll probably have to use something other than `toJSON` for sending data to views (as we've discussed before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10779124/479863 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9687672/479863). I've been meaning to send a patch in to separate these two uses of `toJSON`.

Comment: @muistooshort ,indeed (again), I try to avoid to `override` Backbone methods due the _collateral_ damages. A separate methods for separate uses could be a great idea but I can guess the Backbone supporters answer: _"you can easily define your own `toTemplateJSON()` method, Backbone implementation is focused in simplicity, and it is not meant to solve every personal purpose"_ :)

Comment: @fguillen - no need to call _.clone because _.pick creates a copy of the object that you give it, in this case "this.attributes".

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to override `Model.toJSON()` since probably you want to use the JSON representation in other parts of the code, for example when passing a Backbone model to a micro template.

A better way to customize which attributes are saved is to override [the sync method](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) in your Model object:

```
   sync: function(method, model, options) {
        if (method == 'update' || method == 'create') {
            var newModel = this.clone();
            newModel.unset('ignoredAttribute', {silent: true);
            return Backbone.sync.call(newModel, method, newModel, options);
        } else {
            return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, this, options);
        }
    },
```

This example ignores the attribute called `ignoredAttribute`.

In your code it will be something like this:

```
  var CSEvent = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",
    urlRoot : '/api/events',
    defaults: {
        title : "",
        type : "Native",
        repeatOrOneTime : "OneTime",
        selected : false
    },
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        if (method == 'update' || method == 'create') {
            var newModel = this.clone();
            newModel.unset('selected', {silent: true);
            return Backbone.sync.call(newModel, method, newModel, options);
        } else {
            return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, this, options);
        }
    }
});
```

Another simple option is to put `selected` as a object attribute (not as a Backbone managed attribute), you can still trigger change events using `trigger`. To me this one is the simplest solution for your problem:

```
  var CSEvent = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",
    urlRoot : '/api/events',
    selected : false,
    defaults: {
        title : "",
        type : "Native",
        repeatOrOneTime : "OneTime"
    },
    select: function() {
         this.selected = true;
         this.trigger('selected'); // you can use another event name here, ie. change
    },
    deselect: function() {
         this.selected = false;
         this.trigger('deselected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose a way to achieve this using two of the principles above, without overriding `toJSON()`.

This pattern provides a number of benefits - for example, client-side validation of all attributes before sending only the necessary ones to the server.

Take the following example, where we are providing a way for a user to change their password.

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: {
    username: "",
    password: {
      old: "",
      new: "",
      confirm: ""
    }
  },

  validate: function(attrs) {
    if (attrs.password.new !== attrs.password.confirm) {
      return "Passwords must match";
    }
  },

  toRemoteJSON: function() {
    var payload = this.toJSON();
    delete payload.password.confirm;
    return payload;
  },

  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    if (method == 'update' || method == 'create') {
      var newModel = this.clone();
      newModel.clear({ silent: true });
      newModel.set(this.toRemoteJSON(), { silent: true });
      return Backbone.sync.call(newModel, method, newModel, options);
    } else {
      return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, this, options);
    }
  }

});
```

When the model is `save`d, the `validate()` method is called before the `sync()` method, and therefore it checks if the two new passwords match. The `sync` method then delegates to `toRemoteJSON()` which removes the confirm password field before sending to the server.

The `toRemoteJSON()` function is simply abstracting the `newModel.unset()` part in Diego's solution. But this now means you can define the overridden `sync` in a base object, and objects extending from this only need to define `toRemoteJSON()`.