# Backbone - Access other views of collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a typical structure of a collection holding models.

In the view, each object has an 'edit' button, that should desactivate all 'edit' buttons of other objects.

I wonder what is the best practice of doing that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I came up with the following approach:

Assume that model has a property `status`, and when it is modified to `active` I want to hide the **edit** button in other entries (or simply disable it).

My collection view listens to a change in a model:

```
initialize: function(){
  this.listenTo(this.collection, "change:status", this.triggerEditable);
},
```

The listener callback looks like that:

```
triggerEditable: function(obj){
    var triggerValue = null;

    // I am interested in a status which became 'active' or stopped being 'active'
    if (obj.get("status") == 'active' && obj.previous("status") != 'active') {
        triggerValue = "editable:false";
    } else if (obj.get("status") != 'active' && obj.previous("status") == 'active') {
        triggerValue = "editable:true";
    }

    // for any other status change - return
    if (!triggerValue) return;

    // trigger is fired for all other objects in the collection
    _.each(obj.collection.without(obj),function(otherObj) {
        otherObj.trigger(triggerValue);
    });
}
```

So, when one object becomes active or stop being active, `edidable:false` or `edidable:true` are triggered for all other entries. All I need to do is to add to the model view initializer a listener:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "editable:false", this.disableEdit);
this.listenTo(this.model, "editable:true", this.enableEdit);
```

Here I guess I could combine these two lines into one, first by listening to the `editable` namespace (**how??**) and then by passing an argument to the function (again, how exactly?).

From here it is straight forward - implement the listener callback:

```
disableEdit: function() {
    var e = this.$el.find('button.edit')
    e.attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

If somebody has something to add or to make this solution nicer, I will be glad to hear.
Anyway, hope it will be helpful to others!!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a property `editable` on your models that is default set to `true`. Then when you click the 'edit' button on one of the views, you could loop through all the models of the other views and set `editable` to `false`. On the view you would listen to model changes, and re-render the view. If `editable` is `false` you would disable the edit button.

Comment: Nice one!! Is it possible to add to the model properties which does not exist in the database? How?

Comment: To be honest I've never synced my Backbone models to the server. I can't imagen client side models wouldn't be allowed to have their own properties. You could have a custom implementation of the [sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync) method but that might not be the most beautiful solution.

Comment: See this answer maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941010/client-side-only-attributes-in-backbone