# Can/should a backbone model store (temporary) data that's not on the server?

Tags: backbone.js

With Backbone, I do a somewhat expensive calculation for each Model in my Collection and there can be a lot of Models.  I'm thinking I'd like to store the result in each Model with `set()`, but I don't want to save it to the server.  Is this generally a bad idea?

If that's not good, is the better practice to keep it in an array variable or a Model (a calculations results model separate from the cached server data model)?

Why do I think this might be a good idea?

- I wouldn't ever have to give thought to the array variable's scope/context.
- No looking up the array contents once I have the relevant Model.
- Data is more encapsulated

Why do I think this might be a bad idea?

- Mixes cached server data with calculated local data.
- Probably have to write sync code so that `save()` only saves the attributes the server should get.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Found someone exploring a similar issue, with good discussion: [Custom Model Property in Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779013/backbone-js-how-to-use-a-custom-model-property-in-a-template).

This seems to have a pretty thorough answer that I am exploring: [Backbone Computed Properties](http://kilon.org/blog/2012/02/backbone-calculated-fields/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solutions might be to override the toJSON function of your Model.

This function is called by the save function to get the attributes to be send back to the server.

Looking at the docs of the toJSON function is basically is saying you could use it for your specific purpose:

```
Return a copy of the model's attributes for JSON stringification. This can be used for
persistence, serialization, or for augmentation before being sent to the server.
```

I would personally not consider it as bad practice but all depends on the amount of and the calculations itself that is needed. So it would depend on your specific use case.

Also you could not store the calculated object in your model.attributes object but somewhere in your model instance. That way it would be hidden from the model attributes you will synchronize back and forth with your server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look to see if that's the spot for dealing with the custom save issue, but definitely looking for thoughts as to whether this is a "bad" direction first.

Comment: Just learned that toJSON is closer than I thought.  See above.

Comment: I needed it to be an attribute because it the data grid I'm using (backgrid) accesses it using .get.  The solution I ran with is at http://kilon.org/blog/2012/02/backbone-calculated-fields/, but I'll pick your answer because it was in the right direction.