# Custom properties in backbone model

Tags: backbone.js

I am working on a Backbone application. I wanted to know how can we create custom properties in Models and use them in templates. Here is what I have.

Model

```
CustomerDetails = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
            id: undefined,
            isOnline: undefined,
            profileUrl: undefined,
            userType: undefined
    },  

    // I want to set this new property

    newProperty: function() {
               return this.get("id") + this.get("profileUrl");
    }
```

});

Template where i am trying to access it

```
<script type="text/template" id="customer-details-template">
<div class="message customer-details">
    <%=id%>
    <%=newProperty%>
</div>
</script>
```

I can get the id property but not the newProperty. Can someone help me with this. 
Thanks!

Comment: Where are you expecting `profileUrl` to come from? Is that supposed to be `id + this.get('profileUrl')`?

Comment: yes, basically the idea is to create a new field using the other fields. Will change that in the existing question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone.js - How to use a custom model property in a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779013/backbone-js-how-to-use-a-custom-model-property-in-a-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this might be to override `toJSON` -- remember, that's what gets passed to the template.  Simply call the base class, and then add whatever extra properties you need:

```
CustomerDetails = Backbone.Model.extend({
    toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.attributes;
        obj.newProperty = this.newProperty();
        return obj;
    },
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eRBmy/2/)

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to overriding the toJSON method you can also add the property to your model and set it's value when the model is initialized.

```
var CustomerDetails = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
            id: undefined,
            isOnline: undefined,
            profileUrl: undefined,
            userType: undefined,
            newProperty: undefined 
    },  

    initialize: function(){
        this.updateNewProperty();
    },

    updateNewProperty: function(){
        this.set('newProperty', (this.get('id') + this.get('profileUrl') ) );
    }
});
```

[A fork of McGarnagle's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garethdn/74rjh/)