# How to use Backbone.js to enhance a multi-language website navigation?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internationalization, seo, friendly-url

I have a multiple language website that display several (a dozen) content pages, with pretty urls like this :

```
example.com              <- home for default language (french)
example.com/biographie   <- page 1
example.com/en           <- home for english language
example.com/en/biography <- page 1 english translation
```

I would like to merge pages together and provide full ajax navigation, pretty much like [Pitchfork](http://pitchfork.com/) did. And the most important thing is to preserve non-javascript clients (SEO, social networks and others) page view.

The server is providing the complete webpage, and then when Backbone is initialize, it pre-fetches other pages and inject it into the DOM to speed up navigation. When I navigation to another page, I use Backbone builtin History API to record the new URL in the history and I change my view to display the requested page.

```
var Navigator = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "*page":                "showPage",
  },

  showPage: function(page) {
    this.pages[page].show();
  }

}
```

The issue I have is to manage i18n (I mean translated pages). How can I setup my router to deal with the language ? How should I handle language switch ?

```
routes: {
  "*page":                "showPageFr",
  "en/*page":             "showPageEn",
},

showPageFr: function(page){
  showPage(page, 'fr');
},

showPageEn: function(page){
  showPage(page, 'en');
},

showPage: function(page, lang) {
  // How should I manage 'lang' parameter here ?
  this.pages[page].show();
}
```

I had a look at i18n JS frameworks, but I don't think I need that because I want to translate the entire page content, not some UI elements. All the translation part is managed server-side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865503/backbone-js-how-to-i18n-value-before-passing-to-template

Comment: @Antonimo : I don't understand why this question is related to mine. I do not have a JSON file containing all the content translation, but I rather treat translated page as a different page (with different URL and different ID)

Comment: right, you want to pass the language (/fr/) to the server as attribute, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445353/key-value-pair-params-handling-in-backbone-js-router,
may help

Comment: @Antonimo : Nope, my issue is not on server side. I use Wordpress and have rewrite  rules that manage the language just the way I need it. My issue is on the client. In fact, I think I will have to define a different root when I call `Backbone.history.start` : "/" for French and "/en/" for English. Do you think this could be a good solution ?

Comment: yep, I too needed a solution for this now, and found this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to DashK who drove my on the good road.
The solution is to change the History root when English language is detected.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    language: null,

    initialize: function(options){

        this.language = options.language;
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:'/'+ (this.language ? this.language : '')});
    },

    routes: {
        ":chapter(/*subpage)": "go",
        "" : "go" // match home route
    },

    go: function(chapter, subpage) {

    }
});

// wait for the document to be ready
$(function(){
    var lang;
    if($.url().segment(1) === 'en') { lang = 'en'; }

    new Router({language: lang});
});
```

Then, I do not have to care about the language when I use `router.navigate("some-chapter")` in my code.

Comment: This method has it's own disadvantages. All links on site also should be without market, thus if we open them on another tab we get page for global market, not its localized version. I'm speaking about Single Page Applications, there all links inside the site are served throught backbone router.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is how you can setup your router to keep it cleaner, hopefully.

You've the `BaseRouter` that will pull content for French, and if you want to add an additional language, you'll have to override the `BaseRouter` with a different language code. (See `EnglishRouter`)

```
// This is the base Router
var BaseRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    language: null,
    routes: {
        '*page': 'showPage'
    },

    _bindRoutes: function() {
        // this._bindRoutes() is called in Backbone.Router before
        // initialize(). Overriding native _bindRoutes method to
        // accomodate the custom logic in changing route.
        var me = this;

        if (this.language) {
            console.log('Updating routes for ' + this.language);

            _.each(_.keys(this.routes), function(key) {
                me.routes[me.language + '/' + key] = me.routes[key];
                delete me.routes[key];
            });
        }

        // Call native _bindRoutes method.
        Backbone.Router.prototype._bindRoutes.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    getLanguage: function() {
        return this.language || 'fr';
    },

    showPage: function(page) {
        console.log('Showing ' + page + ' in ' + this.getLanguage());
    }
});

var EnglishRouter = BaseRouter.extend({
    language: 'en'
});
```

Here's the Fiddle that goes with it: http://jsfiddle.net/dashk/yTS33/

In terms of strategizing content for different pages - Based on what you described (All content instead of the normal specific-string,) a single dictionary could be an option. (I don't think it's elegant though.) As you add more languages to your website, however, you may want to consider dynamically loading the languages as needed instead of just putting all languages in a single file.

Here's a sample of the dictionary:

```
var PageContent = {
    'fr': {
        'happyPage': 'Happy Page Content in French',
        'fridayPage': 'Friday page Content in French'
    },
    'en': {
        'happyPage': 'Happy Page Content in English',
        'fridayPage': 'Friday page Content in English'
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer DashK : +1. That seams a good direction to follow, so I will try it and mark your answer as the good one When I will be able to make it work.

Comment: Concerning the content itself, I will not use a dictionary, but the markup itself. My content is full of html markup (with video and image tags). I load it via ajax upon request and insert it into the DOM at the right place.

Comment: I see two issues in your answer. First: in the Fiddle you provide, I see "Happy Page Content in French" when I click on `Happy Page Content in French` link, and the other way round. I cannot understand why, but the logic is inverted. Second: I tried within my own code, and it seems that the `initialize` call is too late to change the routes. Old routes still match and new routes don't after the change.

Comment: sorry, I meant "in the Fiddle you provide, I see "Happy Page Content in French" when I click on `Happy Page English` link, and the other way round."

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux - My mistake. I overlooked that Backbone.Router._bindRoutes was actually called before .initialize(). I've updated the Fiddle and the answer to correct this.