# Backbone.js - proper model initialization

Tags: backbone.js

**Questions:** What is the proper way to initialize a backbone.js model when there are attributes that need to be stored in specific ways? Do i need to map the attributes that don't need any special formatting? I thought backbone.js did some kind of auto-mapping.

**Example:**

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function (options) {

        // These attributes need to be stored in a different format
        // Dates
        this.startYear = new Date(options.startTime).getFullYear();
        // Rounding numbers
        this.wholeNumber = Math.Round(options.numberWithDecimals);
        // Storing empty strings as nulls
        if (options.fullName == null || options.fullName == "") {
            this.fullName == null;
        } else {
            this.fullName = options.fullName;
        }

        // These are fine as they are
        this.fieldA = options.fieldA;
        this.fieldB = options.fieldB;
        this.fieldC = options.fieldC;
    },
});
```

Comment: Are you thinking about [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse)?

Comment: idk. Am I? Is there a better/easier/more proper way to do what I am doing in this example?

Comment: `parse` is called for when your getting the attributes through a `fetch`. That said you [shouldn't](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-constructor) need to manually specify the attributes that don't need modification, and for the ones that do you probably should be using [set](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set) (for example `this.set({startYear:= new Date(options.startTime).getFullYear()})`).

Comment: @Jack: `parse` will also be called by the constructor if you specify the `{parse:true}` option but this isn't documented.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you have to differentiate between `attributes` and `instance variables`.

**Attributes**: IMHO, it should be plain objects as String or Integer. They travel around the client and the server through the REST API. They are manipulated through the [Model.get()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get)/[Model.set()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) methods. They are sent to the server through the [Model.toJSON()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) (also they use to be sent to the `template` using the same `.toJSON()` method. If they change in some way then *Backbone events* are triggered. You can customize the initialization of this `attributes` manipulating the server side JSON information before it is sent to the Model overriding the [Model.parse()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method as @muistooshort has suggested.

**Instance Variables**: (the `this.myAttribute` thing) They can be complex objects. The don't trigger any implicit event in their change and they are not sent to the server in the `save` and `update` calls, and, in an standard way, they are not sent to the *template*.

In your example you're not storing any complex object and if you are not affraid that your model is gonna send more attributes to the server than it receives from the server you can go for the @muistooshort suggestion:

```
// code no tested
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function(resp, xhr) {
    resp.startYear = new Date( resp.startTime ).getFullYear();
    resp.wholeNumber = Math.Round( resp.numberWithDecimals );
    if( resp.fullName == "" ) resp.fullName == null;

    return resp;
  },
});
```

Just remember you these are *attributes*  and you have to access them in this way `my_model.get( "startYear" )`

The only problem with this solution is the *derived attributes* won't be updated if the *original attribute* changes. So you can come with another implementation:

```
// code no tested
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.updateAttributes();
    this.on( "change", this.updateAttributes, this );
  },

  updateAttributes: function() {
    this.set( "startYear", new Date( this.get( "startTime" ) ).getFullYear() );
    this.set( "wholeNumber", Math.Round( this.get( "numberWithDecimals" ) ) );
    if( this.get( "fullName" ) == "" ) this.set( "fullName", null );
  },
});
```

#### Updated

As @TomTu has suggested if your *onlive attributes* are only needed to feed the templates then a **decorator** is the best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9687672/316700

Comment: AFAIK you have to say `new M({...}, {parse: true})` to get the constructor to use `parse`, this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: @muistooshort I think is not needed https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L339

Comment: But if you just do `new M({...})` without a `fetch`: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L187

Comment: @muistooshort Very right! I didn't know that, I hope I'll remember it when is time or it will blow up my mind.

Comment: if you do it this way every time you do a save you send to the server overhead of all the changes and extra attributes you've introduced this way - that's a very bad approach IMO

Comment: @TomTu this is because I said _"if you are not affraid that your model is gonna send more attributes to the server than it receives from the server"_.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is helper values to be used in the templates you can compute them in the overwritten `toJSON` method that will add all the extra attributes that you might need when representing a model in a view.

[As the documentation for Backbone.js says](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON):

> model.toJSON()
>
> Return a copy of the model attributes for JSON stringification. 
>   This can be used for persistence, serialization, or for **augmentation**
>   before being handed off to a view. ...

as I mentioned in a comment for another answer - altering the model in the `parse` method will result with creation of overhead which will be sent to the server every time model is saved and should be considered a sloppy and bad practice

Since the model initialization doesn't bind the options to the instance of the model in similar fashion as it does for the views you can always do that in the initialization method and then refer to the options from the overwritten toJSON method as required by whatever you want to achieve

Comment: I'm not sure but I think if you manipulate `.toJSON()` the manipulation will have an impact in the server communication, so you're in the same issue than in my approach.

Comment: I think here is where it happens: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1359

Comment: had fears I've seen it there - would seem like serializing the attributes property on the model should be a better idea. It seems that providing some kind of alternative to toJSON is the only thing that would make sense without altering the core and not having to update the custom properties on the model every time a change happens. Actually now I recall that I've used to create a method called toTemplateData() just for this purpose as we had requirement for passing some bigger nested data objects which caused major overhead. Might be worth throwing a question about it on the github.

Comment: Exactly, under the premise that the _onlive attributes_ are only needed to feed the templates then a **decorator** is the best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9687672/316700 (but this premise is not mentioned in the question and this is because I came up with the more intrusive approach).. updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Has already been answered but just to be just a bit neater:

```
var contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
       parse: function (response) { 
           response.newAttribute = response.alreadyProvidedAttribute; 
           return response;
      }
 });
```